# Provide Internet access for different VLAN

Tags: linux, security, freebsd, vlan, internet

I have several managed switches at work that connect all computer within our office to the ADSL modem. However I would like enforce a VLAN policy to isolate traffic within the network. Through my previous studies of the CCNA certification it has come clear to me that I would require a router. The router would facilitate routing traffic back and forth between the different VLANs and the ADSL modem.

However I have a limited budget and was thinking to replace the router with a switch running a customized version of Linux or *BSD distro. Would this be viable? If anyone could provide me with guidelines for getting it set up I would be very grateful.

Comment: I've had linux accept multiple vlans tagged onto a single physical interface. Then you can configure linux for each of the vlans to get a virtual interface. Then you would need to configure linux to act as a router. If you want to implement policies, you can use iptables to firewall traffic. Do you prefer FreeBSD, since it seems it can do the same thing.  http://wiki.stocksy.co.uk/wiki/VLAN_configuration_for_UNIX_hosts http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/network-routing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab a workstation with a couple of NICs on it (or buy an [ALIX](http://store.netgate.com/ALIX-Kits-C86.aspx) device) and setup a [router-on-a-stick](http://blog.stefcho.eu/?p=695), or depending on how many VLANs you have, dedicate an interface for each one.  If you're doing a lot of inter-VLAN routing (i.e. workstations on VLAN 1, servers on VLAN 2) then you'll want a layer 3 switch or a real router (or one of [these](http://www.lannerinc.com/x86_Network_Appliances/x86_Desktop_Appliances/FW-7535)).